# Why we can not pass instance variable in swiftUI Priview?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using swift UI code as below

```
struct ABC_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @Binding var boolVar :  Bool
    static var previews: some View {
        FilterDeviceList(isCloseView: isCloseView)
    }
}
```

But its throwing error like "Instance member 'boolVar' cannot be used on type 'ABC_Previews' "

Answer (score 3):

Because `previews` is `static`, ie *type-wide*

You can use something like

```
static var previews: some View {
    FilterDeviceList(isCloseView: .constant(true)) // if binding is expected
}
```